# nginx rendering PHP as plain text

Tags: php, nginx

```
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   test.local;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  root       /var/www/testsite;

  location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Requests to php files just return the code as plain text. Headers do mention PHP, so I presume nginx is talking to PHP properly ..

I've looked over it all too many times now, I feel I must be staring right at the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: You did try everything...except a wildcard *

Comment: Are you accessing www.example.com/index.php or www.example.com/index.php/something ?

Comment: Follow this link it will help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

See if your files are starting with < ? .

If so, and you want to keep them like that, you will need to edit **/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini** and set **short_open_tag** from Off to **On** and restart php-fpm.

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

Search for short_open_tag and set it to On.

Restart php-fpm

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: `<?` without space in between them