# PHP on NGINX not working

Tags: php, nginx

I have an Ubuntu Server 22.04 where I just compiled nginx-quic, PHP has been installed as FPM, the PHP service is up and running, I created an info.php with phpinfo in it, nginx shows me the welcome page when I visit, but when I try to enable PHP on it, it doesn't work, it downloads the file instead of showing the PHP info, this is how I have it configured:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

The lines that are commented where lines I tried before that did not work either.

Any ideas what I can be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check https://askubuntu.com/q/390311/134479 and the suggestions listed there?

Comment: I did and none worked, so I decided to drop nginx, I'll just wait for Apache to have http3 support, do forget about this.